# Android Version code and Version Name Issue

Tags: android, file, apk

I have published my App in Playstore.Now same app with changes i want to    publish in play store again.for that i make changes in menifest file.

In menifest I have this version code and version name

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

Now I can change

```
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2"
```

am i right or not??.

Comment: what is exactly your question ?

Comment: I want to put app in playstore third time so increase version code 2 to 3 and versionname 1.1 to 1.2  it is right or not?

Comment: It's right but you should write versionCode and versionName in build.gradle instead of Manifest if you are using Android Studio.

Comment: no need to change versionCode change only versionName "1.3"

Comment: please give me reason for downvote??

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right. If you are using Android Studio than you should put your `versioncode` and `versionname` in `build.gradle` (Module:app)

```
android:versionCode="2"

android:versionName="1.1"
```

---

if you are using eclipse than you should put your `versioncode` and `versionname` in `MANIFEST`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#appversioning):

> **android:versionCode** — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions. The value is an
>   integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it,
>   for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set
>   the value to any integer you want, however you should make sure that
>   each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The
>   system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with
>   successive releases is normative. Typically, you would release the
>   first version of your application with versionCode set to 1, then
>   monotonically increase the value with each release, regardless whether
>   the release constitutes a major or minor release. This means that the
>   android:versionCode value does not necessarily have a strong
>   resemblance to the application release version that is visible to the
>   user (see android:versionName, below). Applications and publishing
>   services should not display this version value to users.
>
> **android:versionName** — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users. The
>   value is a string so that you can describe the application version as
>   a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>   relative version identifier.

Long story short, yes your new `versionCode` and `versionName` are correct.

The important thing to remember is that you need to increment the number of `versionCode`, `versionName` instead can be whichever string you want, there is no control on this.